# In a SQL GROUP BY query, what value is used for the non-aggregate columns?

Tags: sql

Say I've got the following data back from a SQL query:

```
Lastname Firstname Age
Anderson Jane      28
Anderson Lisa      22
Anderson Jack      37
```

If I want to know the age of the oldest person with the last name Anderson, I can select MAX(Age) and GROUP BY Lastname. But I also want to know the first name of that oldest person. How can I make sure that, when the Firstname values are collapsed into one row by the GROUP BY, I get the Firstname value from the same row where I got the max age?

Comment: your 'max age' doesn't come from a particular row because it is an aggregate. Think about the case when you have another row, ('Anderson','Bob',37) in your set - `max(age)` is still 37 but which row does it come from?

Answer (score 3):

For those RDBMS that support it (e.g., SQL Server 2005+), you can use a window function:

```
select t.Lastname, t.Firstname, t.Age
    from (select Lastname, Firstname, Age, 
                 row_number() over (partition by Lastname order by Age desc) as RowNum
              from YourTable
         ) t
    where t.RowNum = 1
```

For others, you'd need a subquery on Lastname and a join to get Firstname:

```
select yt.Lastname, yt.Firstname, yt.Age
    from YourTable yt
        inner join (select LastName, max(Age) as MaxAge
                        from YourTable
                        group by LastName) q
            on yt.Lastname = q.Lastname
                and yt.Age = q.MaxAge
```

Comment: worth noting that if the maximum age for a given lastname is shared between 2 or more rows, your first example will return just one (unpredictably) and your second would return multiple rows

Answer (score 2):

You have to join back to the table from your grouped results - i.e. create a view or a nested query to contain the group by.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you need to watch out for whatever your approach is that there might be *more than 1* `firstname` with the same age for a given `lastname`.

This query will return just 1 row, but if your data set had more than one 'Anderson' aged 37, it could return either one:

```
select firstname, age
from yourtable
where lastname = 'Anderson'
order by age desc limit 1
```